# I am getting the following error while trying to run Http Test Script Record on jmeter 4.0

Tags: java, jmeter, localhost

I am getting the following error while trying to run Http Test Script Record on `jmeter 4.0` :

```
java.io.IOException:   >> keytool error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: DNSName components must consist of letters, digits, and hyphens <<
Command failed, code: 1
'keytool -genkeypair -alias http://localhost:8787/hammer/home#/home -dname "cn=http://localhost:8787/hammer/home#/home, o=JMeter Proxy (TEMPORARY TRUST ONLY)" -keyalg RSA -keystore proxyserver.jks -storepass {redacted} -keypass {redacted} -validity 7 -ext san=dns:http://localhost:8787/hammer/home#/home'
    at org.apache.jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils.genkeypair(KeyToolUtils.java:171) ~[jorphan.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils.generateSignedCert(KeyToolUtils.java:285) ~[jorphan.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils.generateHostCert(KeyToolUtils.java:276) ~[jorphan.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.initDynamicKeyStore(ProxyControl.java:1540) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.initKeyStore(ProxyControl.java:1447) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.startProxy(ProxyControl.java:530) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.gui.ProxyControlGui.startProxy(ProxyControlGui.java:569) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.gui.ProxyControlGui.actionPerformed(ProxyControlGui.java:424) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_171]
```

I have put in http domain as `http://localhost:8787/hammer/home#/home` and `port` as `8888`. Also configured manual `proxy settings: address- localhost, port: 8888.`
My Certificates are also downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep your domain name as `localhost` as it must correspond to [preferred domain name syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034#section-3.5).

Also in general you don't even need to configure any extra details in order to be able to record HTTP traffic, unless you're not recording HTTPS - there is no need to generate keystore as JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-superpower-http-proxy-server) is able to intercept insecure traffic without [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) proxy.

So I would recommend reverting your changes which prevent JMeter Proxy from starting and record your use case with default configuration.